# Information loss of a 9-input majority gate

Tags: information-theory

According to information theory, the logic gates AND, NAND, OR, NOR all lose 1.189 bits of information each with two bits of information at their inputs and with all inputs being independently and uniformly distributed.

When gates are used in combination with other gates in a circuit, to calculate the entropy loss for the entire circuit you have to use what are called "mixture probabilities" or "mixing distributions" to calculate the entropy loss, the loss for each gate being dependent on the entropy loss history of the preceding gates.

Can anyone calculate the entropy loss of a majority gate with 9 inputs, all equally likely $\{1,0\}$?

Comment: What have you tried on your own?  Are you familiar with the definition of entropy?  Have you tried writing a little program to enumerate the entire truth table, calculate the distribution on the output, and compute its Shannon entropy?  This problem is straightforward if you know the basic concepts, and it's not clear what you have tried.  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking here.

Comment: Why put on hold, I have written a clean concise question and I have a nice answer from Mr Filmus which I have already accepted, what am I missing?

Comment: William, "unclear what you are asking" is a catch-all that encompasses many things (I realize that's not very intuitive). I see that you're new to the site, so you may not be familiar with the site format -- but on this site, we expect you to make a serious effort on your own first and to show us what you've tried, not just to describe the problem statement.  If you'd like the question to be re-opened, see my first comment for suggestions on how you could edit the question to make it more suitable for this site. Thanks for asking!

Comment: No , feel free to close the question if you like, I already have a good answer. If you want to be that narrow-minded about the scope of the questions you allow here, then I think you are doing a dis-service to all the potential contributors to the site. Most of the people that use this are probably not going to be as mathematically gifted as you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first explain what the *entropy loss* is for a gate like AND. The input entropy is $2h(1/2) = 2$ (where $h(p) = -p\log_2p-(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$), while the output entropy is $h(1/4)$ (since the probability that the output is $1$ is $1/4$). Therefore the entropy loss is $2 - h(1/4) \approx 1.189$.

In the case of recursive majority, the output is uniform, so the output entropy is $1$. The input entropy, in contrast, is $9$, and so the entropy loss is $9-1=8$.

Comment: I did not think it was that easy, could you elaborate further as to what it means for the output to be uniform and 1 bit only?

Comment: The output of recursive majority is a single bit which is the recursive majority. For symmetry reasons, the output is $0$ half the time and $1$ half the time (if you flip all input bits, the output bit gets flipped). We say that the output is *uniform*.

Comment: So if any Boolean circuit , no matter how complex or deep, if the truth table of the function is {1,0} balanced, the output entropy is always one, is this correct? What if the inputs to the recursive majority gate are only .811 bits per input instead of 1 bit each, is the output entropy still one or less than one?

Comment: Regarding the output entropy, as far as I can tell this is the *definition* of the output entropy: the entropy of the output given the probability distribution of the inputs. Answering your second question, it depends on the distribution of the inputs. If it is such that the output is uniform, then its entropy will be 1.